# Setting label and value of the chart

Tags: java, jfreechart, label

I am creating pie charts using `JFreeChart`, and I want to set the value and the label seperately like in `iReport`. In other words, I want the chart to show different results on the pie than in the legend. Is there any way that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `MessageFormat` *ArgumentIndex* values correspond to the **series name**, **domain** and **range**. You can set a different generator for each series or for all series in the base.

```
PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setLabelGenerator(new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{0} {1} {2}"));
```

Addendum: For `PiePlot`, the values have a slightly different meaning—**series name**, **value** and **percentage**—as shown [here](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator.html).

Comment: but I don't think I should use BarRenderer, I'm creating a pie chart

Comment: @Halo: Oops! Thanks for catching this. Right principle, wrong `Plot` subclass. Revised above, _and_ I learned something new. :-)