# Display JFreeChart Values

Tags: jfreechart

I have created a pie chart in JFreeChart. However, numerical values are not appearing on the "slices". How do I make it appear there?

Comment: What do you mean on the slices? As in directly on the slices, or on a label on the slice?

Comment: directly. I also want to apply this on a bar chart (on the bar on the other hand)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a `PiePlot` this is possible using a setter `setSimpleLabels`.

Assuming you have your created chart:

```
Chart chart = // your created chart
PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setSimpleLabels(true);
```

If you need an even more plain look you can use a transparent color for the label shadow, outline and background paint:

```
plot.setOutlinePaint(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
plot.setLabelShadowPaint(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
plot.setLabelBackgroundPaint(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
plot.setLabelOutlinePaint(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Edit: To display values instead of legends in the slices:

```
plot.setLabelGenerator(new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{2}"));
```

The `StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator` also has a number formatter if you need one of these.

That should do it for a pie chart.

As for a bar chart you can set the label positions on the `BarRenderer` using the `setPositiveItemLabelPositionFallback(ItemLabelPosition position)` method. For inside labels you could use:

```
barRenderer.setPositiveItemLabelPositionFallback(
     new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.CENTER, TextAnchor.CENTER));
```

Be sure the font size can fit inside the bar when you try this.

Comment: hmm..so the values that will display is the same as that of the values in the legend?

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547244/setting-label-and-value-of-the-chart/3551238#3551238).

Comment: I used this code for the bar graph but the labels didn't show:  
    CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot(); 
    BarRenderer barRenderer =    (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
    
    barRenderer.setNegativeItemLabelPositionFallback(
          new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.CENTER, TextAnchor.CENTER));`

Comment: You should try `setPositiveLabelPositionFallback`. If you have the developer manual for JFreeChart, go look up the label anchor/position definitions.