# JFreeChart pie chart has too many labels so that nothing is readable

Tags: java, jfreechart

Basically I have a grouped by report that has too many groups, so the pie chart has over 50 different pies. I know it doesn't really make sense to create a pie chart for such a report, but is there a better way to organize the labels so that the pie chart is more readable (other than completely removing them)? I did think of combining those after the top 10, or something like that, but in many cases that would be even worse because it's too evenly spread...

Comment: you can hide the labe in pie chart and only show the legend below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few ideas:

- Do not add the (factory default) `StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator`.
- Do use `setLegendLabelGenerator()` to display those same labels in the legend.
- Do enable tooltips, possibly using a custom `StandardPieToolTipGenerator`.
- See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3551238/230513) about `MessageFormat`.

Comment: I looked at using a legend, but a similar problems arises. The legend becomes too massive. Instead of having the pie chart full of labels, now the legend is impossible to read. Any suggestions here?

Comment: You can always invoke `getLegendItems()` and render the items in something like a `JList` or `JTable`.

Comment: If I don't put pieplot.setLabelGenerator(new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{0} ({2})")); a label is still drawn. How do you remove all labels?

Comment: Just figured it out: pieplot.setLabelGenerator(null);

Comment: Alternatively, don't add it as the factory method does.