# How to set Pie chart values in %

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using JFreechart for creating chart. When i am creating pie chart the values for the pie chart are displaying with integer format.But i need those values in Percentage.

```
My current Output :- 

Service manager (1)
Service Executive (6)
Service co-coordinator (3)

My Expected output :-


Service manager (10%)
Service Executive (60%)
Service co-coordinator (30%)
```

Sample code:-

```
for(int i=0;i<dataset_bydeglist.size();i+=2){
                        dataset.setValue(dataset_bydeglist.get(i).toString()+" ("+(Integer)dataset_bydeglist.get(i+1)+") ",(Integer)dataset_bydeglist.get(i+1));
                    }
```

Adding value to dataset.All data are inside arraylist.

Please help me.

Comment: What is the problem in my question?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Is it about setting the values or about output? Where is the rest of your code related to the question?

Comment: Out put is depends on values you have entered.Without some valid values how output is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PieChartDemo2`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/PiePlot.html) is an [example](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) that uses a [`StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator.html) for this. There's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3551238/230513).